# how to flash a virtual MAC address in freescale K64F board

Tags: microcontroller

I got some FRDM-K64F boards, which are the development microcontrollers from
freescale. Surprisingly some of them got the same MAC address. I created the request at freescale about this issue and they said I can flash a virtual MAC address in the MCU using MQX RTOS.
I need to ask what hardware/software tools are required to flash the new MAC addresses in MCU?
If I am not wrong i will ne freescale kinetis design studio, but how can i flash the mac address ? do i need usb cable or any other interface ??
any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

In our projects we use K60 and K66.
The MAC address is stored in MQX in some local variable.
What we did, as was recommended by Freescale, was place the MAC address in a program once registers, read it back on startup and use that when calling ENET_initialize.

We use the JLink commander to write the program once registers using the following commands:

```
w1 0x40020007 0x43
w1 0x40020006 0x00
w1 0x4002000B 0xMAC_B1
w1 0x4002000A 0xMAC_B2
w1 0x40020009 0xMAC_B3
w1 0x40020008 0xMAC_B4
w1 0x40020000 0x80

w1 0x40020007 0x43
w1 0x40020006 0x01
w1 0x4002000B 0xMAC_B5
w1 0x4002000A 0xMAC_B6
w1 0x40020009 0xFF
w1 0x40020008 0xFF
w1 0x40020000 0x80
```

Hope this helps.